# Unable to run swagger generation tool with groupname

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

In our project we have specified two group names for swagger. one is public and another ia private. I was not able to generate the one which is private. since we made our group name as private I was trying below commands to generate.

```
swagger tofile --output swagger.json API.dll v1 private

swagger tofile --output swagger.json API.dll v1 -private
```

it didnt throuw any error also it didnt generate swagger file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the one that doesnt exist, then the tool come up with the list of group that exists.

so, I had to use doublequotes and execute. It was able to generate the swagger json.

The One I tried

```
swagger tofile --output swagger.json API.dll v1private
```

This I have used to generate the file

```
swagger tofile --output swagger.json API.dll "v1 - private"
```

I am not sure and couldnt find in the github that there is a command to list the groups available in the swagger tool already.